How to combine two query results together in C# & ASP.NET MVC controller
I have a table called Complaint_Log and the relevant column names in it are CompanyName and ContactPerson.
What I'm trying to do is generate a partial view for my dash page of a table that loops through the Complaint_Log data and if there is duplicate values of the company name or the contact person, then have it get generated to a list. I also need it to get a count of how many duplicates there are and get rid of the duplicates.
I currently have a query I'm using that works perfect, but it's only for the CompanyName. I can't figure out how to get it to loop through the list and include the ContactPerson (as the CompanyName) IF there is a duplicate of a ContactPerson, but doesn't have the same CompanyName.
For example, lets say this is my list data below that's in my table:



CompanyName
ContactPerson




Company A
Bob Smith


Company B
Fred Stevens


Company A
Rick Moore


Company C
Bob Smith



So as you can see, there are 2 Company A's with a different ContactPerson and 2 Bob Smith's with a different CompanyName.
In this example I'd like my table generated to show:



Customer
Occurrences




Company A
2


Bob Smith
2



If both of the Company A entries had Bob Smith as the ContactPerson, then the above table should only show Company A. I want it set up this way in case there's a person that maybe switches companies or something.
I'm totally stuck on how to achieve this, I literally just cannot figure this out. Maybe the way I'm currently going about it is not the way I should be, but as of right now, I created a model called CompanyAlertModel, a model called ContactAlertModel and a model called CustomerAlertModel. They are all identical except for the name of the models. I'm sure I probably don't need that many models, but since my query worked for the CompanyName like I wanted it to, I made another one doing the same query except I did it for the ContactName.
My goal was to create that third model and combine the queries for the CompanyName and for the ContactName and add it into the third model which is what I'd use for my table I'd generate, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine them.
This is my model (like I said the other ones are the same except for the names):
public class CompanyAlertModel
{
    public CompanyAlertModel() { }

    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Occurrence { get; set; }
    public Complaint_Log Complaints { get; set; }
}

Here is my controller:
public ActionResult CustomerAlerts()
{
    // Get list of all the companies with more than 1 occurrence
    var company = from c in db.Complaint_Log
                  group c by c.CompanyName into g
                  orderby g.Key
                  select new CompanyAlertModel()
                      {
                          Customer = g.Key,
                          Occurrence = g.Count(),
                      };

    // Get list of all the contact names with more than 1 occurrence
    var contact = from c in db.Complaint_Log
                  group c by c.ContactPerson into g
                  orderby g.Key
                  select new ContactAlertModel()
                      {
                          Customer = g.Key,
                          Occurrence = g.Count(),
                      };

    var result = company.ToList();

    return PartialView(result.Where(x => x.Occurrence > 1).ToList());
}

And my table on the view page:
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Customer Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Occurrences
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.Customer
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.Occurrence
            </td>                
        </tr>
    }
</table>

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Create a viewmodel which you have done already and assign the grouped content to relevant properties in that viewmodel. Then send the viewmodel to you partial view to be displayed. Are both the queries that you have shown in the question correct as per your requirement?

@RahulSharma yes, the queries I showed do work correctly, but one of them only does the companyname and the other only does the contactname. In my partial view its only using the first query at the moment. As for your suggestion, that's what I've tried to do so far and am stuck on. I assigned the companyname values to the customer field in the first query, then assigned the contactname values to the customer field in the other query. I tried assigning the customer field values from both models to the customer field in the other model I created, but haven't had any luck.

I've tried combining them using .Concat(), .AddRange(), .Union() and none of those worked with those queries. Do you know how I could group them both into my third model Customer property?

So what is your desired result? I am not able to understand what you want to do with the combined query?

@RahulSharma my desired result is from my main table "Complaint_Log", there are two two field names I'm trying to get the data for. "CompanyName" and "ContactPerson". I want to put the query into a partial view table where it will list any CompanyName value that is in the Complaint_Log that has more than 1 duplicate value. Then, I want it to check the ContactPerson values and if there is any duplicate value of those where the CompanyName is different, then list the ContactPerson. If the duplicate values of the company and the contact person are the same then only list the company name.

I'd like it that way in case the same contact person switches companies and has a duplicate.

In your case, you can generate a generic model to hold the values from your grouped lists. First create a generic view model that we shall pass to your View:
public class GenericModel
{
    public GenericModel() { }

    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Occurrence { get; set; }
}

Now using the exact same piece of code logic that you have, you do a Union on the two grouped lists when using this GenericModel:
public ActionResult CustomerAlerts()
{
    List<GenericModel> myModel=new List<GenericModel>();
    // Get list of all the companies with more than 1 occurrence
    var company = from c in db.Complaint_Log
                  group c by c.CompanyName into g
                  orderby g.Key
                  select new GenericModel()
                      {
                          Customer = g.Key,
                          Occurrence = g.Count(),
                      };

    // Get list of all the contact names with more than 1 occurrence
    var contact = from c in db.Complaint_Log
                  group c by c.ContactPerson into g
                  orderby g.Key
                  select new GenericModel()
                      {
                          Customer = g.Key,
                          Occurrence = g.Count(),
                      };

    var resultForCompany = company.Where(x => x.Occurrence > 1).ToList();
    var resultForContact= contact.Where(x => x.Occurrence > 1).ToList();
    
    //Now merge the two lists since they have are of the same type:
    myModel=resultForCompany.Union(resultForContact).ToList();
    
    //Here you are sending to your partial view a model of type List<GenericModel>
    return PartialView(myModel);
}

Now since we have generic model, your View will expect a Model of type List<GenericModel>. The rest of the display to show the data will be the same that you have posted in your question.

I tried your example and it worked great! I tried to get the .Union() to work before, but it kept giving me errors. I was doing it wrong. I was missing the myModel generic list part. This list was driving me crazy, so thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

To clarify, I was trying different things last week before I posted this question. I was trying to get the .Union() thing to work last week, but didn't have any luck. I've never used it before so I must have been trying to implement it wrong. So how you used it in this example did work!

Glad to hear that. Good luck with your project.

You have to combined results for two queries into the third response.
   var thirdResponse =  from comp1 in company
                          join cont1 in contact
                          on comp1.Customer equals cont1.Customer
                          select new
                          {
                              CompanyName = comp1.Customer,
                              ContactPerson = cont1.Customer,
                              CompanyOccurrences = comp1.Occurrence,
                              ContactOccurrences = cont1.Occurrence
                          };

If you need two results like models use for the View
   var model1 = new companesResultModel();
    var model2 = new contactsResultModel();
    return PartialView((model1, model2));

In the View
@model (companesResultModel model1, contactsResultModel model2)

@foreach (var item in model1)
@foreach (var item in model2)


thank you for your suggestion, I tried playing around with it some and wasn't having any luck. It wouldn't let me pass both models through the partial view. But what I really want to do is when I do the query, like the thirdResponse one you did, is there a way to add the CompanyName list values from the first query(company) and the ContactPerson list values from the second query(contact) to the "Customer" field name in the third model/query? Instead of putting the values in two different fields.
